# What are the #P-hard version of Latin square and sudoku?

Tags: complexity-theory

I know that filling partial latin square and solving sudoku are NP-hard. But what are the counting versions of these two problems?

Comment: You're not automatically guaranteed that these will be #P-hard.

Answer (score 1):

The counting problems corresponding to your two decision problems are:

- Given a partially filled Latin square, in how many ways can it be completed to a Latin square?
- Given a partially filled Sudoku puzzle, in how many ways can it be completed to a Sudoku solution?